# Searching a sentence and scraping the first URL from Google Images

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

i've been trying to find tutorials to solve this problem but none of them seems to be this specific.
I have a program that it's going to deliver a sentence or word (it's already done it has his own funcionality), i need a program that would:
1- Search the sentence or word
2- Give me the URL of the first result in Google Images
nothing else. How can i do this?

The program that delivers the sentence it's the next one:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#cantidad de items (el event activa el Enter)
def cantidad_items(event):
    
    global x
    
    x= int(texto1.get())
    texto1.delete(0, END)
    
    texto1.bind("<Return>",añadir)
    boton1.configure(text = "Ingresar", command=añadir)
    
#nombre de los items e impresión
def añadir(event = None): #No entiendo, explicación: bind() runs with argument, command= runs without argument
    
    item = texto1.get()
    lista.append(item)
    texto1.delete(0, END)
    
    if len(lista)== x:
        texto1.destroy()
        boton1.destroy()
        rando = random.choice(lista)
        resultado = Label(window, text=rando, font= "Helvetica 30")
        resultado.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor= CENTER)

#main -------------------------------------------------------------------

x = 0
lista = []

#generación de ventana
window = Tk()

window.title("Decidir que mierda hacer con Mora")
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(background="light blue")

#descripciones
label1 = Label(window, text="Introduzca la cantidad de ítems", background="light grey")
label1.place(relx = 0.5, rely= 0.35, anchor=CENTER)

#primer entry del número
texto1 = Entry(window, font = "Helvetica 20", width = 22)
texto1.bind("<Return>", cantidad_items)
texto1.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)

#firma
firma = Label(window, text="Hermicode",font = "Times 10", background= "light blue")
firma.place(relx = 1, rely= 1, anchor=SE)

#botón ejecución del input
boton1 = Button(window, text = "Ingresar", command = cantidad_items)
boton1.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, anchor= CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add information about your workflow (i.e. what data you are already able to access) and what information you are hoping to get. Show code snippets where relevant.

Comment: there you go :)